# Preposition with the noun “password”

Tags: prepositions

> 1. What’s the password *of/to/for* your wifi?

Which preposition can be used here? I have heard many people say “of” in my country. However, I personally use “for”. I would like to know the correct usage.

Comment: I think you can also ask *"what's your/the Wi-Fi password?"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that all are valid. I would use any of the three, depending on how I feel, but probably more likely to use "for" and least likely to say "of".